# Matching leftover with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match anything that isn't the previous match with regex.

I have the following regex:

```
(?<return>return)|(?<other>(?![ \n]).*?(?=(?:[\s\n]|$)))
```

If I use it on the following string, I get one match for the `return` group

```
return
```

But on the following string I get the `other` group:

```
 return
```

(notice the space before the return).

The regex for other shouldn't match any spaces (or new lines) however (due to the `(?![ \n])`.

So, for example let's say I have the following string: `return abc 123`. Then I'd like to have 3 matches using the above regex: one in the `return` group which contains "return", and two in the `other` group containing "abc" and "123"

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Does anyone have an explanation for this? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean you need to capture `return` into "return" group, and the rest (as the space before `return`) into an "other" group? Sorry, `(?![ \n]).*?(?=(?:[\s\n]|$))` is too messy and can be better written as `\S+`, but I doubt it is what you need. Or, does it? Try `(?<return>return)|(?<other>\S+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry for my poor wording. I'll give an example of what I want: let's say I have the following string: `return abc 123`. Then I'd like to have 3 captures: one in the return group which captures "return" and 2 in the other group capturing "abc" and "123". Hope this clears it up a little more.

Comment: Does [this work](https://regex101.com/r/H41Ujp/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
(?<return>return)|(?<other>\S+)
```

It matches

- `(?<return>return)` - Group "return": a `return` substring
- `|` - or
- `(?<other>\S+)` - Group "other": one or more non-whitespace chars.

If the `return` can appear inside a non-whitespace chunk, you might want to exclude `return` from the second part: `(?<return>return)|(?<other>(?:(?!return)\S)+)`. See  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/H41Ujp/2).

If there must be a whitespace or start of string on the left, and a whitespace or end of string on the right, you may add whitespace boundaries:

```
(?<!\S)(?:(?<return>return)|(?<other>\S+))(?!\S)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H41Ujp/3).